# How do you convert code from rxjs v5 to rxjs v6 for catch?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am following a tutorial from thinkster.io about coding "Services for Interacting & Authenticating with a Server" using angular 2+. I got stuck upon this section using RXJS v5 and was unable to convert it into the new RXJS v6 to make the code work.

I am working on the following files form where I am getting the error:

user.service.ts

```js
    import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
    import { BehaviorSubject } from 'rxjs';
    import { ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
    import { map, catch } from 'rxjs/operators';


    @Injectable()
    export class UserService {
      private currentUserSubject = new BehaviorSubject<User>(new User());
      public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();

      private isAuthenticatedSubject = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);
      public isAuthenticated = this.isAuthenticatedSubject.asObservable();


      attemptAuth(type, credentials): Observable<User> {
        let route = (type === 'login') ? '/login' : '';
        return this.apiService.post('/users' + route, {user: credentials})
        .map(
          data => {
            this.setAuth(data.user);
            return data;
          }
        );
      }

      getCurrentUser(): User {
        return this.currentUserSubject.value;
      }

    }
```

api.service.ts:

```js
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, catch } from 'rxjs/operators';

  private formatErrors(error: any) {
     return Observable.throw(error.json());
  }

  get(path: string, params: URLSearchParams = new URLSearchParams()): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.get(`${environment.api_url}${path}`, { headers: this.setHeaders(), search: params })
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

  put(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.put(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

  post(path: string, body: Object = {}): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.post(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      JSON.stringify(body),
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }

  delete(path): Observable<any> {
    return this.http.delete(
      `${environment.api_url}${path}`,
      { headers: this.setHeaders() }
    )
    .catch(this.formatErrors)
    .map((res:Response) => res.json());
  }
}
```

Running the code would give me the following error: ERROR in src/app/shared/services/api.service.ts(5,15): error TS1003: Identifier expected.

The only way to get rid of it is to comment out this line of code
`public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();`. But the code would not run as expected by the tutorial.

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like all you need to do according to the migration document is change `catch` to `catchError` and utilize the new piping syntax.

See [HowTo: Convert to pipe syntax](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md#howto-convert-to-pipe-syntax):

> The following operator names were changed because their dot-chained
>   names are reserved words in JavaScript:
>
> - `do` -> `tap`
> - `catch` -> `catchError`
> - `switch` -> s`witchAll`
> - `finally` -> `finalize`
>
> To convert dot-chained operators to pipeable operators, wrap all
>   operators in the pipe() method from the source observable, remove the
>   dots, and add commas to pass each operation to pipe() as an argument.
>
> For example, the following code uses chaining:
>
> ```
> source
>  .map(x => x + x)
>  .mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2)
>    .filter(x => x % 1 == 0)
>    .scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0)
>  )
>  .catch(err => of('error found'))
>  .subscribe(printResult);
> ```
>
> To convert to piping:
>
> ```
> source.pipe(
>  map(x => x + x),
>  mergeMap(n => of(n + 1, n + 2).pipe(
>    filter(x => x % 1 == 0),
>    scan((acc, x) => acc + x, 0),
>  )),
>  catchError(err => of('error found')),
> ).subscribe(printResult);
> ```

Comment: Ok I fixed this part! But I still get an error on this line: 

`public currentUser = this.currentUserSubject.asObservable().distinctUntilChanged();`
core.js:1624 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: this.currentUserSubject.asObservable(...).distinctUntilChanged is not a function
TypeError: this.currentUserSubject.asObservable(...).distinctUntilChanged is not a function